# Premature exit and destructors

Tags: c++

I'm writing a linux deamon in a class, which is a smart pointer of an App class:

App.hpp

```
class App
{
public:
    App(void)
    {
        this->ptrDaemon = std::make_unique<Daemon>();
        this->ptrDaemon->ptrApp = this;
    }
    ~App(void) = default;

    // Members
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Daemon> ptrDaemon = nullptr; // This is constructed in the constructor
};
```

Daemon.hpp

```
class Daemon
{
    ~Daemon() = default;
    App *ptrApp = nullptr; // This pointer is assigned to the app instance in the App constructor
    bool daemonise()
    {
        pid_t pid{};

        pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0)
        {
           return false;
        }
        
        // Exit father 
        if (pid > 0)
        {
           this->ptrApp->~App(); // This works, but is it a good practice?
           std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        // More code
    }
}
```

In this case, I need to exit the father process prematurely, so if I used `std::exit(0)` the smart pointer wouldn't be freed. To avoid that, I used the other objects destructor.

Is it a good practice (looks ugly to me)? Is there any other solution I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to free the smart pointer? When your process exits, the OS frees all its memory.

Comment: In this case is not very necessary, but in other use cases it might be. However, in class they always demand no memory leaks.

Comment: By calling `exit()` you are potentially not calling a lot of destructors. If you want to exit after `"daemonizing"` why not get `main()` to exit normally, thus doing a graceful exit (I am not worried abut destructors in terms of memory management but rather in terms of correctly cleaning up other resources (but that may not be an issue for your application)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a good practice (looks ugly to me)?

No, it is usually not a good practice to call a destructor in a member function.

> Is there any other solution I could use?

Sure. Here are a few:

1. Don't bother deallocating. The "memory leak" won't matter since the process is about to be terminated. Note that if the destructor does something more than just deallocate memory, then this may not be an option. Also consider that `App` instance might not be the only object that doesn't get destroyed.
2. Don't terminate prematurely using `std::exit`, but instead return from `main` like normal. This is the only approach that ensures that all destructions are taken care of.

Comment: Special mention to (1). Memory leaks are only relevant as long as the process continues existing (generally, when code is being run in a loop and leaking heap allocations). If the process is dying, the memory is going back to the OS anyway, so destructors are often a formality in that situation.

Comment: `std::exit` is normal termination, atexit handlers will be called.  Fast abnormal termination does exist, but `std::exit()` isn't it.

Comment: As described in [the wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), it will call destructors of global objects but not those on stack. It's not clear from OP's code whether `App` instance is on stack.

Comment: @anatolyg Damn. I rolled back my edit. I had mislead myself with a broken example that I made.